# How do I force re-rendering of a row in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, css, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid in raw javascript (ie- no angular, no jquery). The grid shows streaming data and dynamically updates with new rows as they come in. My goal is to highlight rows that are less than 20s old in a different color.

I can easily apply css classes on a row-by-row basis when they are initially rendered, but I can't figure out how to remove the css classes when they become older than 20 seconds. Here is what I am doing:

```
  class TickerController {
    constructor() {
      ...
      this.gridOptions = {
        rowClass: 'ticker--row',
        rowClassRules: {
          '-new-row': params =>
            (Date.now() - params.data.accepted_time) < NEW_ROW_THRESHOLD
        }
      };
      let tickerGrid = this._getElementById('ticker-grid');
      new agGrid.Grid(tickerGrid, this.gridOptions);
    }
    ...
  }
```

You can see here that I am applying a `ticker--row` class to all rows and a `-new-row` class to rows that are new. This does highlight new rows, but I don't know how to re-apply the `rowClassRules` on a periodic basis.

Can someone explain the proper way to achieve my goal of removing the `-new-row` class when the row is no longer new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[plunker for demonstration](https://plnkr.co/edit/V7r5KRb2unMwJTXt4h8g?p=preview)

Here is one way that it could be done:

1. have a data value in the row to hold the information of whether or not to highlight the row
2. define the rowClassRules to look at that data value
3. when a new row is added, create a timeout to trigger in 20 seconds to update this value.

---

```
var gridOptions = {
    ...
    rowClassRules: {
      'highlight': 'data.lessThan2'
    }
    ...
};

function onInsertRowAt2() {
    var newItem = createNewRowData();
    var res = gridOptions.api.updateRowData({add: [newItem], addIndex: 2});
    printResult(res);
    setTimeout(updateItems,2000,res)
}

function updateItems(rows) {
  var updatedRows = rows.add.map(row => row.data)
  updatedRows.map(e=>e.lessThan2 = false)
  gridOptions.api.updateRowData({update: updatedRows})
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. I will try this out shortly and get back to you.

Comment: Works like a charm.